# In Haskell, how to explictly give a signature to this particular subfunction with inherited parameters?

Tags: haskell, signature

Say you have this function

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef

f :: (Num a, Ord a) => STRef s a -> ST s ()
f i = loop
        where
            loop = do
                _i <- readSTRef i
                writeSTRef i (_i - 1)
                when (_i > 1) loop
```

in `loop`'s body, `i` is implictly defined as it is a parameter from `f`.
However I'm having a trouble giving a signature to `loop`. Hie shows me that it should be `ST s ()`, so I write `loop :: ST s ()` just above `loop`'s definition.

However ghc complains that it cannot match the `s` from `loop` with the `s` from `f`. As `loop` has no parameter it creates its own local `forall s.` in that loop's definition which prevents matching with `f`'s `s`.

But surprisingly it compiles without explicit signature.  PartialTypeSignature works but it's ugly and doesnt allow reference to `s`. It also compiles if I just add `i` as parameter to `loop` but let's say I'm lazy.

How can I exlicitly specify `loop`'s signature in a way that compiles?

Is it not true that everything that compiles with implicit types, can be given explicit types so that it still compiles?

Comment: Does `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` fix it?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I don't think so. It's a "can't match ```s``` with ```s1```" kind of error.

Comment: add explicit `forall s.` in `f`'s type signature. (or perhaps `forall s a.`...). with the `ScopedTypeVariables` of course.

Comment: don't use `forall s.` in the `loop`'s signature. it should work. :)

Comment: @WillNess The  problem, is that it is created automatically by ghc, even if i don't specify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution does indeed lie in `-XScopedTypeVariables`

The issue comes from the fact that if you want to refer to an already existing type variable, that variable must be explicitly quantified.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef

f :: forall s a. (Num a, Ord a) => STRef s a -> ST s ()
f i = loop
        where
            loop :: ST s ()
            loop = do
                _i <- readSTRef i
                writeSTRef i (_i - 1)
                when (_i > 1) loop
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure to understand the reason it changes behavior. Even if I didn't write forall, wouldn't there still be an implicit forall s a in ```f``` ? Why does it suddenly understand what to do?

Comment: @jam The issue is that there would also be an implicit `forall s` in `loop :: ST s ()`, and this new `s` is not the same as the one in the type of `i`. To denote that we really want the same `s`, without the implicit `forall`, modern Haskell decided to require the explicit `forall` on `f`. It is not a terribly obvious notation, but it's meant to override the legacy Haskell semantics -- arguably this was a defect in the legacy Haskell definition.

Comment: @jam Essentially, the new rule is: implicitly quantify every type variable in every signature, unless that variable was explicitly quantified at an outer point. So, to reuse `s`, explicitly quantify it above, and do not quantify it below: that prevents the implicit quantification below.

Comment: I believe this is why purescript decided to *always* force you to explicitly quantify type variables. not doing so makes things ambiguous, and you have to come up with unintuitive rules like this one in haskell!